# windows - change REG_SZ reg value with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to change the "CommonFilesDir" value, with a batch file. But it is not working. What am i doing wrong ? Or is it not possible to change a REG_SZ value ?

```
reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /v CommonFilesDir /d "A:\Program Files\Common Files" /t REG_SZ /f
```

It just execute, apparently with no errors, but the value it doesn't change. I also tried with only `reg add..` and i got the same

Comment: Don't do it, it isn't supported and will break things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format it like the following:

```
reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /f /v CommonFilesDir /t REG_SZ /d "A:\Program Files\Common Files"
```

*(Be sure to run as an administrator.)*

Comment: I will try and later i'll bring some answers

Comment: just one more doubt, this code `reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" /f /v CommonFilesDir (x86) /t REG_SZ /d "A:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"` they are not changing the key, do you know why ?

Comment: Forget it, i figured out. I just put a double quote before and after of the key value's name, like this `"CommonFilesDir (x86)"` and works. However, thank you very much anyway!